# How to unify variables in SMT-LIB

Tags: z3, smt, quantifiers, unification

I am trying to do this in SMT-LIB, running `z3 -smt2 script.smt2` on the script containing these expressions:

```
(set-logic AUFLIA)

(declare-fun a () Int)
(declare-fun b () Int)
(declare-fun c () Int)
(declare-fun d () Int)
(declare-fun e () Int)
(declare-fun f () Int)
(declare-fun x () Int)
(declare-fun c () Int)

(declare-fun addition (Int Int) Int)

(assert (= x c))
(assert (= c (addition a b)))
(assert (= f (addition d e)))

(check-sat)
```

I want to get a unification for these variables. For example, I expect to be able to unify the variables by assigning `x=f`, `a=d` and `b=e`.

Is it even possible to do this in `z3` or `SMT-LIB`?

Or should I be using some other language to do this (maybe give a recommendation is this is what you think?)

Comment: I'd be somewhat surprised if Z3 had explicit support for the feature you describe. Did you search for variable elimination, or for minimal models, in the context of Z3? Also, a (cumbersome) approach could be to repeatedly query Z3 while adding explicit equalities such as `x=f`, and to record the query that used the most equalities and was still satisfiable.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there is an explicit way to do this. You can do `(get-model)` and get the variables with different integer assignments cannot be equivalent, while those with the same integer assignment could be substituted for each other.